# biblatex: remove commas between last and first names in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am new to `biblatex`, and I need to create a bibliography with the authors' names with last names followed by pure initials. Using the `style=numeric`, `firstinits` and `terseinits` options along with:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
```

I come up with a list of names that looks like:

> Doe, J, Smith, K, and Doe, W"

How can I remove the commas between the last name and the initial of the first name?

Answer (score 28):

EDIT: Since `biblatex` v2.2, one may simply issue `\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}` in the document preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[firstinits=true,terseinits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, Aaa and Buthor, Bbb and Cuthor, Ccc},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL ANSWER: Redefine the bibmacro `name:last-first`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[firstinits=true,terseinits=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
     {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%      \ifblank{#2}{}{\addcomma\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}% DELETED
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}% NEW
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%      \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\addcomma}% DELETED
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, Aaa and Buthor, Bbb and Cuthor, Ccc},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: @lockstep: I just saw your solution and used it in my .tex file, works well in the end, but no matter what I do, I keep getting the error : Undefined control sequence. argument> \bibnamedelimd \mkbibnamefirst {Patrick}\isdot Patrick is in that case the firstname of the author. I keep getting this error for every first-/lastname. What should I do? Sorry, I have just started working with Biblatex...

Comment: `\bibnamedelimd` was introduced in `biblatex` version 1.3. Try to update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\bibliographystyle{Vancouver}` as well for removing the commas

Comment: Please note that `\bibliographystyle{Vancouver}` is a BibTeX-based solution, while the question and other answer are using `biblatex`.

Comment: Noted with Thanks