# Biblatex style file for New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)

Tags: biblatex

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`biblatex-nejm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nejm)

The journal *New England Journal of Medicine* (NEJM) has the following requirement for references. I can't find a standard style file. What is the closest match? How can I customize based on that?

In the citation, it looks like `1–3, 7, 8` (no square parentheses) at the end of a sentence .

For bibliography, list all authors when there are six or fewer; when there are seven or more, list the first three, followed by `et al.` The following is a sample for article type:

> Shapiro AMJ, Lakey JRT, Ryan EA, et al. Islet transplantation in
>   seven patients with type 1 diabetes mellitus using a
>   glucocorticoid-free immunosuppressive regimen. N Engl J Med
>   2000;343:230-8.

**EDIT 1**:

*Question 1*

The bib entry for this article:

```
@ARTICLE{Shapiro2000, 
   author = { Shapiro, A M J and Lakey, J R T and Ryan, E A and Lisa Schreiber and Jon Smith and Allan Jones and Cathy Smith},
   title = { Islet transplantation in seven patients with type 1 diabetes mellitus using a glucocorticoid-free immunosuppressive regimen},
  journal = { N Engl J Med },
  year = {2000},
  volume = {343},
  pages = {230-8}  }
```

I have fixed the author initial thing. Now it is the

> N Engl J Med 2000;343:230-8.

part I need help. I really appreciate your time and help.

*Question 2*

In the bibliography, how can I get "1." in stead of "[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)"?

**EDIT 2**:

*Question 3*

The journal name should not be italic. Can we make it right?

*Question 4*

Suppose there is an entry field `number = {2}` in the bib item, how can we prevent it from showing up in bibliography?

*Solution 5*

tips from @[lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep):

please google: `biblatex`: remove commas between last and first names in bibliography

`terseinits=true` seems not working with `backend=biber`

When I removed `backend=biber`, the `terseinits=true` started to work.

many thanks to @[Marco](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco)

Comment: Looks like you're requesting code to define a style, which is a lot to ask in a single question. You've also only provided one example entry, and this probably isn't enough information to specify the style. Next time around you might want to consider breaking up your problem into questions and providing as much detail as possible up front.

Comment: @Audrey: yes I start to realize I am requesting too much. Definitely next time I will do good homework before posting 'good' and clear questions. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Marco: It is great idea. Actually you have already finished most part of it.

Comment: @Marco: It is great idea. Actually you are already almost there. It would be a huge help to the medicine/biology people who use less LaTex.

http://www.nejm.org/page/author-center/manuscript-submission

Here is their link. Their bibliography requirement is in the middle part of the page. 

another piece: 
 % to remove quotation marks from {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot} 

Their citations require '\supercite'

Comment: @Audrey: I get to know better how StackExchange works. I have just registered. My reputation is only 8 now, not enough to give me right to upvote -- of course I will try to earn more 'reputation' to upvote Marco's answer. Creating a style by myself? It sounds impossible. But I will give it a try since I have your support -- it will be slow when I learn little by little.

Comment: @tlw: see my edited post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT** (31.08.2011 17:00 CET)
I build a small package which allow you to use:

```
\usepackage[style=nejm,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

The package consists of the modification of this threat and the examples of NEJM.

The package is now on CTAN.

**EDIT** (30.08.11 09:00 CET) Now all 5 questions are implemented in the code.

`terseinits=true` works with biber. You need also the option `firstinits=true`

Now I use the bib-entry of [tlw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7519/tlw) to modify the style `numeric`

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Shapiro2000, 
   author = { Shapiro, A M J and Lakey, J R T and Ryan, E A and Lisa Schreiber and Jon Smith and Allan Jones and Cathy Smith},
   title = { Islet transplantation in seven patients with type 1 diabetes mellitus using a glucocorticoid-free immunosuppressive regimen},
  journal = { N Engl J Med },
  year = {2000},
  number={2},
  volume = {343},
  pages = {230-8}}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,%
            minnames=3, maxnames=6,%
            terseinits=true,%
            firstinits=true,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
     {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}%remove \addcomma
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\addcomma}%%commented
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}

%Name-scheme in thebibliography
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
%cite without brackets
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
%no bracktes in thebibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}
%no pp
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
%no In by journal name:
\newbibmacro*{in:}{}
%Order year;volume:page
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printtext{%
%  \printtext[parens]{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon}
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
%  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon}
%Journalname roman
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
%no number
\newbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}%
%  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\cite{Shapiro2000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with `minnames=3`, so that if there are 7 or more authors the list is truncated to 3.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks to you and rcollyer. I got the citation format and the number of authors list fixed. How can I get "Journal Name 2000;343:230-8"? Thanks for your patience and help to the newbies.

Comment: using the bib entry like this: 

@ARTICLE{Shapiro2000,
author = { Shapiro, A M J and Lakey, J R T and Ryan, E A and Lisa Schreiber and Jon Smith and Allan Jones and Cathy Smith},
title = { Islet transplantation in seven patients with type 1 diabetes mellitus using a glucocorticoid-free immunosuppressive regimen},
journal = { N Engl J Med },
  year = {2000},
  volume = {343},
  pages = {230-8}  }

Comment: @Marco The name format still needs some tweaking. The OP is replacing first names with initials by hand in the `bib` file, but this is unnecessary. The format in [a previous answer by lockstep](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/biblatex-remove-commas-between-last-and-first-names-in-bibliography/17593#17593) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for digging up this question after all this time but I think I have something to contribute.

I've used the package that resulted from this question and found some issues with it. I managed to fix them and I thought that maybe somebody else could use it. I tried adding a comment on the package page but the website doesn't work (the ajax request returns 404).

My changes are related to minnames which I set to 6 (but that might not be what everybody else wants) but more importantly I fixed some issues that arised out of changes in other packages.

If it helps anyone, I'm adding the updated version here. If you need to change the minnames back to 3 that should be simple enough.

```
%% Copyright (C) 2011 by Marco Daniel 
%% 
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%% 
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2008/05/04 or later.
%% 
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%% 
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is Marco Daniel.
%% 
%% This work consists of the files nejm.bbx, nejm.cbx, biblatex-nejm.tex
%% and biblatex-nejm.pdf

%%$Id: nejm.bbx 28 2011-09-09 17:17:01Z marco $
%%$Rev: 28 $
%%$Author: marco $
%%$Date: 2011-09-09 19:17:01 +0200 (Fr, 09. Sep 2011) $
\def\biblatexnejmversionbbx{v0.4}
\def\biblatexnejmpackagenamebbx{nejm.bbx}
\def\biblatexnejmsvnbbx$#1: #2 #3 #4-#5-#6 #7 #8${#4/#5/#6\space }
\ProvidesFile{nejm.bbx}[\biblatexnejmsvnbbx$Id: nejm.bbx 28 2011-09-09 17:17:01Z marco $ \biblatexnejmversionbbx: \biblatexnejmpackagenamebbx]

%use numeric.cbx as base
%Warning if backend isn't biber
\RequireBiber[2]
%need style:
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}

%set options to biblatex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
{
    isbn         = false ,
    labelnumber  = true ,
    minnames     = 6 , 
    maxnames     = 6 ,
    firstinits   = true ,
    terseinits   = true ,
    sorting      = none ,
%   language     = nejm ,
}


%provide original option
\providebool{bbx:subentry}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{subentry}[true]{%
\setbool{bbx:subentry}{#1}}

\providetoggle{bbx:articledoi}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{articledoi}[false]{%
\settoggle{bbx:articledoi}{#1}}

\providetoggle{bbx:articlein}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{articlein}[false]{%
\settoggle{bbx:articlein}{#1}}

\providetoggle{bbx:printlang}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{printlang}[false]{%
\settoggle{bbx:printlang}{#1}}


%specify language
\DeclareListFormat{language}{%
\iftoggle{bbx:printlang}{%
        \usebibmacro{list:delim}{%
            \ifbibstring{#1}%
                {\bibxstring{#1}}%
                {\ifbibstring{lang#1}%
                    {\bibxstring{lang#1}}%
                    {#1}}}%
            \ifbibstring{#1}%
            {\bibstring{#1}}%
            {\ifbibstring{lang#1}%
                {\bibstring{lang#1}}%
                {#1}}%
        \usebibmacro{list:andothers}%
}{}%
}

%format date -- only year printed
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}{%
\edef\blx@tempa{\bbl@main@language}%
}{%
\edef\blx@tempa{\blx@languagename}%
}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{\blx@tempa}{%
%<year><month><day>
\protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}%
    }%
\protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}%
}%  
}

%Set environment
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
    {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\defbibenvironment{shorthands}
{\list
    {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

%%
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
\entryset
    {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
    {\printfield[bibentrysetcount]{entrysetcount}%
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}}
    {}}
    {}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{setpageref}%
\finentry}

%remove punctuation and space after initials -- require biber
\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitperiod}{}
%separator printed before the pages field
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon}
%no bracktes in thebibliography and add dot
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
%not formating pages
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{#1}
%not formated journaltitle
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
%not formated title
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}


% %Set name format
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
% %Not needed??
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{last-first}

%remove comma between familyname and firstname
\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
\ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
    \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
    \ifblank{#3}{}{%
    \ifcapital
        {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
    {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
    \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
    \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
    \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
    \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}%remove \addcomma
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
    \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
    \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
    \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\addcomma}%%commented
    \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
    \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}

%option articledoi -- no doi / eprint / url in article
\newbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url-use}{%
    \iftoggle{bbx:doi}%
        {\printfield{doi}}%
        {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}%
        {\usebibmacro{eprint}}%
        {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:url}%
        {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}%
        {}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
\ifentrytype{article}%
    {%
    \iftoggle{bbx:articledoi}%
    {\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url-use}}{}%
    }{\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url-use}
    }%
}

%no bibstring in in article:
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
\ifentrytype{article}%
    {\iftoggle{bbx:articlein}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}{}}%
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}

%no number in ouput of bibliography
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
\printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}%
\iffieldundef{number}{}{(\printfield{number})}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
    \printfield{year}%
    \iffieldundef{month}{}{\space\printfield{month}}}%

%Order year;volume:page
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
\printtext{%
    \iffieldundef{issue}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}}}%
\newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
% author2: \usebibmacro{author} ;\space
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{issue+date}%
\setunit*{\addsemicolon}
\iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}%
\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{issue}%
\newunit}

\endinput
```

If there is enough need for this updated version, I'm willing to figure out a way to make the changes more thought through (i.e. add the package on some kind of repository that supports versioning and make my changes clearer, possibly with added comments on the reasoning).

There's been some time since I worked on it though so it'll take a while for me to understand again what I did and why.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: After [registering an account](https://www.ctan.org/join) you can add a comment to the [CTAN package page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nejm). The first page of [the package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-nejm/biblatex-nejm.pdf) also shows an email address. And asking a question as told by Bobyandbob above is also recommended and IMHO would be a good idea, even if you already know the answer. On the other hand, hijacking a maintained package isn't a good idea. Please read the LPPL for information about what to do.

Comment: I did make an account on CTAN and adding a comment didn't work. When I clicked save nothing happened, I looked at what was happening and the ajax request that triggered on click was giving me a 404.

I don't think it's hijacking a package since it's a legitimate issue the package has. What I'm bringing is a bugfix basically. Maybe it does work for others, in which case I guess I need more information.

I will try adding another question that's related to the issues I was having.