# Overwrite citation/reference style in apa6

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa6

I'm submitting and article to Translational Behavior Medicine and their formatting requirements are for everything to be in accordance with APA, except citations/references, which must be in AMA format.  I've been trying to figure out how to modify apa6.cls but I'm getting lost.  My preamble begins with

`\documentclass[man, apacite,  letterpaper]{apa6}`

and when I've tried to change the `apacite` option to `natbib` or `biblatex`, I get errors.

I've used LaTeX quite a bit, but I have never really gotten into the back-end stuff, so I'm a bit lost.  Any help with modifying `apacite` or suggestions for other workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

As requested, I'm also including a descrition of AMA style as provided by the journal.

1. Cite references in text using numbers in square brackets (e.g., “Behavioral Medicine spans many disciplines [1,2]….”)
2. Journal article with one to six authors:
   Salwachter AR, Freischlag JA, Sawyer RG, Sanfey HA. The training needs and priorities of male and female surgeons and their trainees. J Am Coll Surg. 2005; 201: 199-205.
3. Journal article with seven or more authors:
   Fukushima H, Cureoglu S, Schachern PO, et al. Cochlear changes in patients with type 1 diabetes mellitus. Otolaryngology. 2005; 133: 100-106.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. For those of us who aren't fully familiar with the AMA style for citation call-outs, could you provide a link to a site that explains the issues and/or provide some examples of how AMA-style citation call-outs differ from those that adhere to APA6 guidelines?

Comment: shouldn't there be a template provided by the journal you're going to publish in?

Comment: The `apa6` class is independent of the `apacite` package and any other method for doing citations. See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/2693). So if there is an existing AMA bibliography style for either `natbib` or `biblatex` then you can use that, but otherwise you would need to modify an existing style, in which case I would use `biblatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I did not see an existing AMA bibliography for natbib or biblatex package.  An ama.bst file does exist though.  Does this help?

Comment: @Mico  Thanks for the welcome.  As requested, I added a description to the original post.  On a separate issue, how can I get the code and packages text to the the nice formatting with the grey background?

Comment: The `ama.bst` style works, but is very old and I don't think it conforms with current AMA style. For example, it will print out full first names of authors, but current AMA style appears to want initials with no periods (e.g. Smith, AM).  Unfortunately the standard numeric style from `biblatex` is quite far off from the AMA style, so it would be quite a bit of work to adapt it I think.  There may be other styles already made that are closer. I'm not familiar with any numeric styles, however, so I can't offer any suggestions. You might want to ask Joseph Wright in the chat.

Comment: On the formatting issue (I assume you mean here on the site?) you can select code and click on the `{}` icon or type CTRL-K.  For small pieces of code use backticks `

Comment: The following might be helpful:  [Biblatex style for New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26891/2693).

Comment: Thanks!  While the NEJM package you linked to was not a perfect match, it was close and I was able to modify the code used to create the NEJM package to meet my needs.  
One quick question.  My Latex script includes the following: 
`\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} `
`\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1} `
`\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1} ` 

Is there anyway to specify this globally for all entry types?