# Override citation style in apa6

Tags: citing, natbib, apa-style, apa6

I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371291/overwrite-citation-reference-style-in-apa6) question that looks similar, but it doesn't have a clear answer.

I am using the `apa6` class to write a paper in the APA format. However, I need to use a less verbose citation style (for e.g. ACM) instead of the usual APA style.

Since the `apa6` class automatically sets the style for citations, how do I override the default?

Currently, my preamble has the following:

`\documentclass[a4paper,man, natbib]{apa6}`

Adding

`\bibliographystyle{stylename}` and changing `stylename` to [something else](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles) like `plainnat` or `ksfh_nat` isn't helping.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> Since the `apa6` class automatically sets the style for citations ...

This claim isn't quite correct. If you load the `apa6` document class *without* one of the options `biblatex`, `apacite`, or `natbib`, no citation management package is loaded and no bibliography style is chosen.

Here's an excerpt from page 10 of the user guide of the [apa6 document class](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6) (highlighting added):

[image]

Maybe slightly counterintuitively, then, in order to achieve your formatting objectives you should **not** specify the `natbib` option while executing `\documentclass`, since doing so loads the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style -- which is precisely what you don't want to do.

What to do? (a) Drop the `natbib` option from the `\documentclass` directive, (b) load `natbib` along with suitable options via a `\usepackage` statement, and (c) issue a suitable `\bibliographystyle` directive. For instance,

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % numeric-style citation call-outs
\bibliographystyle{acmtrans} % or some other suitable bib style
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{apa6}

% Create a bib file "on the fly"
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa:3001,author="Anne Author",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{acmtrans} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\cite{aa:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that isn't working for me. I get ? ? ? in the references.

Comment: @wrahool - Did you also perform a full recompile cycle -- latex, bibtex, and latex twice more -- after applying the suggested changes? How do you load the `natbib` package, and which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: My first three lines in the preamble are as follows:
`\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}`
`\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`
`\bibliographystyle{acmtrans}`

And yes, I did a full compile cycle twice over (FWIW, I'm doing this on Overleaf not on my desktop client)

Comment: @wrahool - With your code, you should be getting several warning and error messages, such as a complaint about `\shorttitle` not being defined. Don't ignore such messages. Specifying the `man` option tells LaTeX to execute, among other things, `\RequirePackage[natbibapa,bibnewpage]{apacite}`. This clashes with the subsequent `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` directive. That's not what you want, is it? The solution: don't specify the `man` option.