# bst file for "National Library of Medicine" citation and reference formatting?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have searched this for hours but still no luck, obviously doing something wrong.  The journal (Risk Analysis) wants "Reference style is based on the National Library of Medicine (NLM) style guide. In-text citations are numbered, superscripted and in parentheses, and the reference list is numbered in order of appearance within the manuscript. Footnotes are superscripted without parentheses".  Could someone please suggest an appropriate .bst file to use that will produce this?
Thanks, J

Comment: Just to give you a sense of how non-trivial your question is, the [NLM citation guide](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7256/) is a 2000 page document. Unless someone has created a `biblatex` style or `.bst` file for it explicitly it's unlikely that one of the standard styles will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, If I understand well your question, you searching  something like this (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver). Basically, the vancouver style is based on nlm. norme(http://guides.bib.umontreal.ca/disciplines/247-Citer-selon-le-style-Vancouver). Hope that can helps.

Comment: @NajlaBioinfo Thanks for this. It does look like the same style, and it's fairly up-to-date. Perhaps you can turn your comment into an answer. And you could probably post the same answer to this question too: [Overwrite citation/reference style in apa6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371291/2693).

Comment: See also [Biblatex style for New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26891/2693).

Comment: @Alan Munn You are welcome. I’m glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look here:

- [ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver).

Basically, the vancouver style (http://guides.bib.umontreal.ca/disciplines/247-Citer-selon-le-style-Vancouver) is based on nlm. norme .

- Same interesting answers here ([Biblatex style for New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26891/biblatex-style-file-for-new-england-journal-of-medicine-nejm)) as suggested by @Alan Munn

Hope that can helps.