# biblatex: How to get 'Annual Reviews' (Style 2) references?

Tags: biblatex

I struggle with some `biblatex` settings (Style 2 of Annual Reviews):

1) The citations in the text should appear with parentheses instead of brackets
and ampersand instead of 'and', so:  Tex et al. (1), Ba & Rise (2).

2) In the references, the entries should appear like this

1. Tex L, Bar F, Rate P. 2011. Minimal title. *Journal of LaTeX
   questions*. 1(1):110--20
2. Ba K, Rise S. 2012. Minimal title. *Journal of BibLaTeX questions*. 1(1):110--31

I tried to adapt the numeric style (in order to get consecutively numbered
citations), but that might not be a good idea (?). For example, concerning 1), I
found
[biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style)
but the trick by A. Munn there to get rid of the parentheses around the year
does not seem to carry over to numeric citation styles.

I know that some
requirements are probably hard to get (for, example, the page range 110--20
instead of 110--120), but any help towards achieving 1) and 2) is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=numeric,
sorting=none,
firstinits=true,
terseinits=true,
uniquename=init,
maxcitenames=2,
date=iso8601,
urldate=iso8601
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@Article{foo,
    author={Tex, La and Bar, Foo and Rate, Pi},
    journal={Journal of LaTeX questions},
    pages={110--120},
    title={{Minimal title}},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    year={2011}}
@Article{bar,
    author={Ba, Ka and Rise, Sun},
    journal={Journal of BibLaTeX questions},
    pages={110--131},
    title={{Minimal title}},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    year={2012}}
 \end{filecontents*}

% bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.}% use 1., 2., ... in the references
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{% use volume(number) for articles for example
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{(#1)}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}% remove quotes from title
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}% remove in label
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{ISBN #1}% format isbn number
\bibliography{bib.bib}% bibliography data
\renewcommand*{\cite}[2][]{\textcite[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]; see \cite{foo}, \cite{bar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace brackets with parentheses for *all* citations, you should take the definitions of citation commands in `numeric.cbx` and replace every instance of `\mkbibbrackets`, `\bibopenbracket`, and `\bibclosebracket` with `\mkbibparens`, `\bibopenparen`, and `\bibcloseparen`. In my example, I've patched the `textcite` bibmacro.

To place the year immediately after the author(s) in the bibliography, I've used sort of a hack: Use `bibstyle=authoryear`, but copy the definition of the `bibliography` bibenvironment from `numeric.bbx`. (One also has to redefine `sortname` instead of `default` when using  `\DeclareNameAlias`.)

To compress page ranges, use `\mkcomprange`. See section 4.6.4 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
citestyle=numeric,
bibstyle=authoryear,
sorting=none,
firstinits=true,
terseinits=true,
uniquename=init,
maxcitenames=2,
date=iso8601,
urldate=iso8601
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@Article{foo,
    author={Tex, La and Bar, Foo and Rate, Pi},
    journal={Journal of LaTeX questions},
    pages={110--120},
    title={{Minimal title}},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    year={2011}}
@Article{bar,
    author={Ba, Ka and Rise, Sun},
    journal={Journal of BibLaTeX questions},
    pages={110--131},
    title={{Minimal title}},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    year={2012}}
 \end{filecontents*}

% bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.}% use 1., 2., ... in the references
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{% use volume(number) for articles for example
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{(#1)}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}% remove quotes from title
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}% remove in label
\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{ISBN #1}% format isbn number
\addbibresource{bib.bib}% bibliography data
\renewcommand*{\cite}[2][]{\textcite[#1]{#2}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{\addcolon\space}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibopenparen}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}{\bibclosebracket}{\bibcloseparen}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\unskip\mkcomprange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mkcomprange{#1}}

\begin{document}
Some text; see \cite{foo}, \cite{bar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi lockstep, many thanks for helping. I had to use `\newcommand` for `\revsdnamepunct` (was undefined) to work. Then, I get a similar output as you, but the references appear as "Tex, L, Bar, F, Rate, P." so with commas (?). I use the basic biblatex as comes with texlive 2012 (on Ubuntu 12.10). Apart from that, do you know how to get "1(1):110--31" instead of "1(1), 110--31"? Many thanks again.

Comment: @MariusHofert a) If you *really* can't upgrade to `biblatex` v2.2 (which introduced `\revsdnamepunct`), use my original answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/biblatex-remove-commas-between-last-and-first-names-in-bibliography b) See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the latest version from https://github.com/plk/biblatex/downloads and put the content in my local TeX tree: (./tex/latex/biblatex in /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex and ./bibtex in /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local (replaced the existing "bibtex" there)). Then a made texhash. On compiling the .tex, I obtain "/usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:87: Miss
ing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> D l.87 ?". Hmmm... not sure what goes wrong.

Comment: I also obtain this error for other documents which involve biblatex, so it's an error in the installation. Line 87 in biblatex.sty is the last line which contains code. I'll accept your answer and open a new issue with the installation problem.

Comment: Okay, it's solved now, the SF version (2.4) worked fine.

Comment: Hi lockstep, do you know how to remove the space after the colon? I expected it to be the `\space` in `\xapptobibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{\addcolon\space}{}{}` but that does not seem to affect the problem.

Comment: @MariusHofert I added `\unskip` as sort of a hack.