# Updating biblatex using mpm

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to get biber to work, and for this I need the most updated version of biblatex.

I used the MikTex package manager

```
mpm --update=biblatex
```

(I also tried uninstalling and installing biblatex.) However, after restarting TeXworks and compiling using pdfLaTeX, the bcf file says

```
bcf:controlfile version="2.6"
```

rather than the most current version which is 3.0. (Presumably, this is why biber (2.0) doesn't work.) What gives? What's the right way to update biblatex? Do I have to install biblatex manually?

My MikTex version is 2.9.

Comment: First thing to do would be to check for duplicate files. You can update A as often as you like and see no difference if B is used.

Comment: miktex hasn't yet updated biblatex and biber. You will either have to update manually or wait until the next update day, or use biber 1.9.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer 
This means that the package manager is a centralized system just managed by MikTeX?
I just updated biblatex manually, using the instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84624/how-to-upgrade-biblatex-properly. (FIrst I had to creaea local texmf tree: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Neither has TeX Live (unless, I assume, you are testing the new one). What I mean is, it is not a specific failing of MiKTeX (if it is a failing at all, which I tend not to think).

Comment: The `bcf:controlfile version` is not the same as either the `biblatex` or the Biber version. There is a correspondence between the `bcf` version and `biblatex` and Biber versions, though (`bcf` version 2.6 comes from `biblatex` v 2.9/Biber 1.9). MikTeX hasn't updated its repositories to `biblatex` 3.0/Biber 2.0 yet. I suggest you wait a few days until MikTeX also gets the new versions. Manual installs are often messy and can lead to malfunctions if done improperly.

Comment: @cfr: I do test texlive 2015, so I have the new biber/biblatex.

Comment: MikTeX has been updated to the newest version. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic since this was all more or less intended behaviour.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has been fixed in the meantime. MikTeX now provides Biber 2.2.

Comment: Sorry, above that should have been *Biber 2.1*.