# What is the safest way to update Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, installing, biber

I have made my presentation in beamer and now I want to use \footcite to add citations. My current Biblatex version is 1.5 which I suppose is old. I saw following post

[How to upgrade 'biblatex' properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84624/how-to-upgrade-biblatex-properly)

but this too seems to be old. Can someone please tell me what is the safest way to update this package. I dont want to mess up with my almost-finished presentation.

Comment: You should update your whole LaTeX system; from another question of yours, you are using TeX Live2011, which is really old.

Comment: Thats the proble. I dont know how to do that. When I google it so many XxxTex names start to show up and I am just an enduser. And I find them very intimidating

Comment: Should I install a new version as suggested on this page https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html

Comment: I'd suggest you to do a fresh new installation as described in https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: This answer could also be of interest for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1094/3954

Comment: I have downloaded it and installation is in progress. Just wanted to ask that what should i do next? Will my TexMaker automatically identify new version and will use it for compiling my .tex file. Or do I need to uninstall the older version first and then proceed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27151/discussion-between-naasi-and-gonzalo-medina).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is being solved (has been solved by now, we should hope!) by updating the TeX installation.