# How to update BibLatex and biber manually on Windows?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

How can I update my `bibLatex` and `biber` on my Windows 7. I currently have `biber 2.3` and `biblatex 3.0`

I have a file called "thesis.tex" and a reference file called "ThesisRef.bib"
I am using the command prompt with following order of commands:

1. pdflatex thesis
2. biber thesis
3. pdflatex thesis

First command i get some warning regarding the reference to figures and labels
but when i run the command "biber thesis". I get following log

```
    INFO - This is Biber 2.3 
    INFO - Logfile is 'thesis.blg' 
    INFO - Reading 'thesis.bcf' 
    WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9
    INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
    INFO - Processing section 0
    INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'ThesisRef.bib' for section 0
    INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
    INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'ThesisRef.bib'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable =non-ignorable'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
    INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'
    INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable =non-ignorable'
    INFO - Sorting list 'nyt' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'
    INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
    INFO - Writing 'thesis.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
    INFO - Output to thesis.bbl
    INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

When I run the third command I get the following error

```
    Package biblatex Warning: File 'thesis.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.6.
    <thesis.bbl
    !Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition
    1.21 \sortlist {
                 nyt}{nyt}
```

From other similar question, I figured that I need to make my biber and biblatex version compatible.
However I don't know how to do that on Windows. I tried downloading the *biber.exe* 2.4 file and replaced it with existing file in `C:\Users\$Name\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\` and also `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64` and then `Refresh FNDB`
It doesn't work.

Can someone please tell me, how I can update the `biblatex` and `biber` on Windows 7(64 bit)?

Comment: [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks for the reply. However this answer doesn't mention which folders should I replace in the windows directory. The automatic update mentioned doesn't work for me.

Comment: Simply launch `MiKTeX Update Manager` (both in administrator an user modes). Current versions are `biber 2.5` and  `biblatex 3.4`.

Answer (score 3):

**You should not update `biblatex` and Biber manually.** It is almost always better to let your TeX distribution sort that out.

In MikTeX you need to run the Updater in both User and Admin mode (maybe you have to run each version twice) to update your packages. See also the very detailed [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864). In TeX live you use `tlmgr` for updates.

If you have any manual installations of `biblatex` and Biber you need to remove those, so they don't get picked up instead of the proper ones placed by your distribution.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84624/35864