# Updating biblatex

Tags: biblatex

First of all, I need to say I am new to both LaTeX and to Linux. I am using ubuntu 14.04. And I have to update my version of `biblatex`.

I know it has been described before, e.g. in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84624/how-to-upgrade-biblatex-properly). But I have a few questions about the answers given and also I am not sure if that process is still the same.

So as far as I understand I have to download the latest version of `biblatex`first. This can be done on `SourceForge`. Is this an official LaTeX site ? 
Anyways, how would I have to replace the version, I mean, I don't know what version is the latest.

Then, in the answer provided in the link I have given, there is the line: `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist`

I have checked, my texlive version can be found under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist`

So am I right to assume I just need to replace the `/local`by `/share`and leave out the year ?

Comment: Welcome, if you are new to it all, why don't you start with up to date software instead of using an old setup and start to patch bits by hand. Ubuntu 16.04 give you long-term support and has a recent TeX Live 2016 packed (at least i think so).

Comment: If you install [Vanilla TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/) directly from TUG, you are independent from your operating system and its repositories and get the most recent updates by default.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 is already installed. So, do you suggest to remove my version of TeX Live and then reinstall a new one? I found [this link](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/16/install-tex-live-2016-ubuntu-16-04-14-04/). Would it be sufficient to simply type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive`in the command window? - Sorry, i need sth simple in the beginning, like the exact commands. .. I don't even know how to completely delete the old version of TeX Live. Is it just `rmdir texlive`when I am in `/usr/share`?

Comment: You don't even have to remove the old TeX Live (assuming you have enough disk space). Just follow the link in my earlier comment.

Comment: ok. I followed your link. I have done the following: - How to acquire TeX Live: other methods;  - Installing TeX Live over the Internet; - install-tl-unx.tar.gz; - I have moved the downloaded "install-tl-20170121" to my desktop; - I have opened the command window and typed cd install-tl-20170121 and then `sudo apt-get install iprint`; ... I still don't know if it has worked. I think I still need to " add the directory of TeX Live to my path" using `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux:$PATH`. But I don't know what to replace `i386-linux`by. It's all a little confusing for me.

Comment: You don't need to substitute anything.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you think this is a duplicate or do you want to write a specific answer explaining that updating certain packages alone is not a good idea and hint at the Vanilla install?

Comment: @moewe You are the biblatex expert. You are more able to write a good answer than me.

Comment: @Johannes_B OK, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the greatest idea to manually update `biblatex` and Biber.

And it is truly a terrible idea to update only one of the two manually, as that will almost inevitably lead to version conflicts between the two.

Updating `biblatex` and Biber manually can lead to version conflicts with packages that require `biblatex` (mostly custom styles - last year `biblatex` received an update that broke many styles to a point that they couldn't be used any more) or with packages that `biblatex` requires (most of these are stable, so this is less likely to happen, but not impossible).

Ideally you would only update your packages via your TeX distribution (`tlmgr` or the MikTeX Update wizard). Some TeX live distributions that are packaged on Linux don't allow for updating with `tlmgr` and rely instead on (often rather old) versions of packages in their official repository.

You can install a vanilla TeX live that lets you use `tlmgr` and gets updates from CTAN directly instead of the outdated repositories of your Linux distro. See [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)

If you really, really must update your packages manually, the general procedure from the answer you linked to should still be valid.

There are a few points though

- Make sure to actually download the current version of `biblatex` and Biber. Check in the documentation that the versions you downloaded are actually compatible. (At the time of writing this `biblatex` is at 3.7, Biber at version 2.7.)
- The correct place for `biblatex` is your local tree [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/35864) You had better not overwrite `/usr/share` content.
- SourceForge is not an 'official' LaTeX site. But the `biblatex`/Biber maintainer updates it with the newest release and development versions when they come available, so the release versions you find there are in a way official. You can get 'really official' package versions on CTAN. `biblatex` is at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex and Biber can be found at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber