# biber raises `dyld[29525]: Library not loaded` error after updating to MacOS Monterey

Tags: biblatex, biber

Biber previously working now raises this error

```
dyld[29525]: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/wp/v5wwzf1j1cn10m3b5d3rf3rc0000gn/T/par-6461766964656c656761636369/cache-6bef3f811cde577dd70e44f9f5046ebc66712c46/biber
  Reason: tried: '/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libperl.dylib' (no such file)
```

after updating to MacOS Monterey. The closest I could find around is [this discussion on github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/403). I tried to reinstall biber & biblatex manually following the instructions [how-to-upgrade-biblatex-properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84624/how-to-upgrade-biblatex-properly), but paths do not coincide and I don't want to make a mess; and with Tex Live, but I get this error:

```
Unable to determine repository version

You have TeX Live 2015 installed, but the version at ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/ cannot be determined.
```

I tried also to update Tex Live as described in [texlive/quickinstall](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) by `perl install-tl`, which did not work either.

I am now trying to follow the instructions in [updating-biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349854/updating-biblatex), but any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: That is a pretty ancient TeX Live. How was it installed; e.g., via MacTeX, Fink, etc? Please update your installation to teX Live 2021. This may be done via the MacTeX installer if you're using macOS 10.14 or later or dong a manual install. Please go to [https://www.tug.org/mactex/](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) for information about either method (the second method is under the Unix Download link).

Comment: I did install Tex Live 2021 and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What eventually worked was:

- [download Tex Live 2021](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)
- [run the installer](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html): `./install-tl -guy = text`
- Set the path in Texmaker:
  [image: Texmaker path]
- Delete the temporary files (`.aux, .bbl, .bcf`)
- Run PdfLaTex + Biblatex + PdfLaTex (x2)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with "eventually"?

Comment: Just "at the end".