# biblatex broken overnight

Tags: biblatex, errors, texlive, bugs

As late as last week my setup for `biblatex` worked fine. Going back to the same project today not even a minimal file compiles:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}

test%foo\nocite{*}   
%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

but breaks off with

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:3776: LaTeX 
Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3776   australian,newzealand}
? 
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:3776: Math f
ormula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts.
\expandafter ->american|

l.3776   australian,newzealand}
```

And keeps repeating the last one until

```
 (That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
```

when I ignore it.

Files without `biblatex` work as expected.

Using `tlmgr` to go my two backup versions of `biblatex` back in time to 1st Jan I still get the same errors.

Could this be another update from the last week or so that causes this?

If I swich back to TL 16 things work as expected. (For my work I need TL 17 because of packages.)

Comment: I worked around this issue by reverting back to the previous version of etoolbox.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is due to a (faulty) change in `etoolbox`, or rather an oversight in a change: see https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/issues/19. A temporary fix is to patch around the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\long\def\etb@listitem#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\@gobble#2}
    {}
    {\expandafter\etb@listitem@i
     \expandafter{\@secondoftwo#2}{#1}}}
\long\def\etb@listitem@i#1#2{#2{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

An update is on the way to CTAN and will therefore be available within around 48 hours *via* the usual channels.

Comment: typical tex.SE-problem: cannot accept perfect answer because of time restrictions ;)

Comment: I can confirm that the 2.5c update of etoolbox avaible on my CTAN mirror now solves the problem.

Comment: New version is now in TeXLive! I just updated and problem solved!

Comment: Same problem occurs on MiKTeX. I did a clean reinstall today and have updated packages, but the problem persists. I presume MiKTeX updates are lagging behind CTAN. Anyway, the workaround is great. Many thanks.

Comment: @LimnoLeon As of this morning the 7. Feb. update ships `etoolbox` v2.5c which fixes this issue (apparently there is still another issue https://github.com/josephwright/etoolbox/issues/20, but that does not affect `biblatex`).