# mdframed broken in TeXLive2017

Tags: mdframed, xkeyval

Since an update of TeXLive2017 through tlmgr yesterday, mdframed seems broken:
the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

throws this error (with latex,pdflatex, lualatex)

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.384   \kvsetkeys{mdf}{framemethod=default,}

? ^C! Interruption.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                              \endgroup 
l.384   \kvsetkeys{mdf}{framemethod=default,}
```

Maybe an error with xkeyval ?

Comment: `\kvsetkeys` is not a `xkeyval` macro. Looks like `kvoptions`

Comment: I tested your code and there were no problems, but I have to update right now in order to see whether an update introduces the problem. `mdframed` itself has no upvotes for years now, however

Comment: Works ok after todays update. Perhaps a side effect of the etoolbox bug which appeared yesterday but is gone by now.

Comment: After update there is no problem with `mdframed` etc.

Comment: No problem here either using a fully updated TL17. If the problem persists the OP should perhaps post the log file for a compilation of this very MWE. Perhaps there is a local package lurking around somewhere.

Comment: It's a problem due to the buggy `etoolbox` version 2.5b; with version 2.5c (released 2018/02/06 and today on TeX Live mirrors) it disappears.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413898/35864. Maybe the workaround mentioned there also works for you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It appears so. Today's update, that included etoolbox, fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem due to the buggy `etoolbox` version 2.5b; with version 2.5c (released 2018/02/06 and today on TeX Live mirrors) it disappears.

With version 2.5b I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.384   \kvsetkeys{mdf}{framemethod=default,}
```

The error is *not* due to `\kvsetkeys`.

Update `etoolbox` to version 2.5c (released 2018/02/06 and on TeX Live mirrors since 2018/02/07) and the problem will be solved.