# LyX and BibTeX problem

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I have a question about the LyX and BibTeX.

For some reason, BibTeX is not working in LyX 2.2.3 ( windows 10 computer). And I got this.

My setting is Natbib and biber, and I followed this instruction:

"Using Biblatex with LyX 2.2 and earlier"
https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Even the simple examples provided in that website do not work.

This is the example
https://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/BibTeX/Bibliography-BibLaTeX.zip

Anyone knows that is the problem? Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you make a .lyx minimal example maybe someone can take a look. For more information, please see: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Yup. There is an example, which are from the LyX wiki directly. You can download it and run in in LyX, and then see the issues.   https://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/BibTeX/Bibliography-BibLaTeX.zip

Comment: You might consider trying LyX 2.3.0rc2, available here: ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.3/lyx-2.3.0rc2/ . It is just a test version, so it is not recommended to use it for serious work. And if you test it, back up all of your documents. But since 2.3.0 will have native support for BibLaTeX, that might make things easier for your.

Comment: Looks as though you are actually using `biblatex`. There is a known `etoolbox` bug that causes this. An update should fix this. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413898/35864