# Biblatex Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am trying to add a bibliograph to my document but I keep encountering the same error. My mwe is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Lettenmeier.2017}
\end{document}
```

And I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3776   australian,newzealand}

?
```

I checked the biblatex.sty and the lite it refers to is:

```
\DeclareCaseLangs{%
  american,british,canadian,
  english,USenglish,UKenglish,
  australian,newzealand}
```

I already tried adding the `babel` package:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
```

But I get the same error. Does anyone have a clue what I might be doing wrong?

My `refs.bib` file looks like:

```
@article{Lettenmeier.2017,
 author = {Lettenmeier, P. and Kolb, S. and Sata, N. and Fallisch, A. and Zielke, L. and Thiele, S. and Gago, A. S. and Friedrich, K. A.},
 year = {2017},
 title = {{Comprehensive investigation of novel pore-graded gas diffusion layers for high-performance and cost-effective proton exchange membrane electrolyzers}},
 pages = {2521--2533},
 volume = {10},
 number = {12},
 issn = {1754-5692},
 journal = {{Energy {\&} Environmental Science}},
 doi = {\url{10.1039/C7EE01240C}}
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Update the `etoolbox` package. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/706 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413898/35864

Comment: `doi = {\url{10.1039/C7EE01240C}}` should just be `doi = {10.1039/C7EE01240C}` but that does not cause the error in question. The double braces in `title = {{Comprehensive investigation of novel pore-graded gas diffusion layers for high-performance and cost-effective proton exchange membrane electrolyzers}},` are useless and should be avoided. The double braces in `journal = {{Energy {\&} Environmental Science}},` are not completely useless, but don't do anything in your example - and rarely at all.

Comment: I updated the `etoolbox` package with the same MWE and now latex prints whatever is inside the brackets of `\cite`, prints square brackets and makes it bold e.g. if instead of `\cite{Lettenmeier.2017}` i write `\cite{foobar}`it will print: [**foobar**] and ignore the `refs.bib` file.

Comment: Have you run Biber on your document? See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for hints on why you need to run Biber and [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help with running Biber.

Comment: It works now with Biber instead of Bibtex. I had to update Biber because it had compatibility issues. Thanks!