# biblatex: blx@packageincompatibility error for blank document

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility

I recently upgraded my LaTeX packages via MikTeX. Afterwards, not even the simplest document will compile with `pdfLaTeX` as soon as I load `biblatex`. According to the package information I have version 3.16 installed. The error message I get is

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.202 b
       lx@packageincompatibility
```

The solution from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413899) had no effect. If I comment out the line

```
blx@packageincompatibility
```

in `biblatex.sty` (line 202 in V3.16) everything works fine. The thing is, I did not load any of the packages that biblatex checks for incompatibility.

Any hints?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413899
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \makeatletter
% \long\def\etb@listitem#1#2{%
%   \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\@gobble#2}
%     {}
%     {\expandafter\etb@listitem@i
%      \expandafter{\@secondoftwo#2}{#1}}}
% \long\def\etb@listitem@i#1#2{#2{#1}}
% \makeatother
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

Hello world!
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: works ok for me, show the complete log-file.

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine for me without any error. As Ulrike says, we need to see the full `.log` file (it might be too long to be included here, so you can upload it to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: All I can say for now is that line 202 in `biblatex.sty` should not be `blx@packageincompatibility`, [it should be `\blx@packageincompatibility`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L202). Your error message is consistent with your `biblatex.sty` missing the ```\```  and having only `blx@packageincompatibility`.

Comment: Weird. I had a look at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty. Seems the beginning ` \ ` was missing in the version of `biblatex` I updated to. Well, adding it fixed the problem. Thanks. Could one of you please add an answer in order to mark the question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is consistent with line 202 of your `biblatex.sty` being just

```
blx@packageincompatibility
```

[instead of the correct](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L202)

```
\blx@packageincompatibility
```

I don't know why your `biblatex.sty` is missing the `\`, all I can say is that [according to `git blame`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blame/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L202) the line has been unchanged in `biblatex.sty` since [it was added more than two years ago in version 3.12](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/82fdf53f93c93709b10c361a5bd47b99a5724df1). (In particular there never was any release version of `biblatex` that was missing the `\`.)

I would recommend uninstalling `biblatex` and re-installing it to make sure that your files are OK and that there are no other `biblatex` files that are corrupted. (Since you are using MikTeX this can be done easily via the MikTeX Console.)