# How to get the biber script with a custom texlive installation?

Tags: biblatex, biber, tlmgr

I installed texlive in my Xubuntu 18.04.4 in `~/texlive/2019/` (updated to texlive 2020) because I thought I would be on the edge for package updates instead of relying on `apt`.

I installed biblatex with `tlmgr install biblatex`. I thought this would come bundled with `biber`... nope (file's not on my system).

I can't simply apt install it because that would pull the entire texlive distribution with it...

So if I follow answers from [How to upgrade 'biblatex' properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84624/how-to-upgrade-biblatex-properly), my only solution is to download it from sourceforge?

It's confusing because the experimented people who answered stated in bold "Do not update biblatex or Biber manually"... So my question: what is the recommended way to install `biber`? Why isn't `biber` installable with `tlmgr`?

Comment: In theory `tlmgr install biber` should let you install Biber (unless you are on a more exotic system for which no Biber binaries are built). Unfortunately, TeX live 2019 is frozen now, so it may be that `tlmgr` won't let you install new packages from the repositories. In that case `tlmgr -repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final install biber` *might* help. If not, you may need to install TeX live 2020 to live on the edge again.

Comment: Errr, you're right! But, why doesn't it appear in the results of `tlmgr search biber`?? (That why I didn't bother trying the install command). Amazing, thanks.

Comment: @moewe Your comment is the answer if you want to fill it ;) As for the distrib, I had just updated to TexLive 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TeX live you can (and should) normally install Biber via

```
tlmgr install biber
```

Biber binaries are built for the most common operating systems and are then also available in TeX live.

Ideally you would update your system with `tlmgr update --self --all` after you installed Biber to make sure that `biblatex` is up to date (so that the `biblatex` and Biber versions match) and that all of its dependencies and all `biblatex` styles are updated as well.

---

In case there was any doubt, `biblatex` should likewise be installed via

```
tlmgr install biblatex
```

in TeX live and not manually.