# Follow-up to "How to call biber"

Tags: texstudio, biber

The accepted answer of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber/34136) writes:

> To compile you should now call `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`.

The problem for me is that I am under TeXStudio and I don't know how to call `biber`...

**Edit**: With the MWE of the acepted answer, I get the following in the output of TeXStudio:

```
Process started: bibtex "document-28-04-21-22p55".aux
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: document-28-04-21-22p55.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file document-28-04-21-22p55.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file document-28-04-21-22p55.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file document-28-04-21-22p55.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

Unfortunately, I don't really know how to fix this...

Comment: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754/134144), especially may be interesting.

Comment: The message you show clearly indicated you are running BibTeX (`This is BibTeX`) but you need to call Biber. Refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754/134144 on how to configure your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get the error 
`Error: One command expansion invalid.`
    `Parent Command: bibliography`
    `Primary Command: bibliography`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually is `pdflatex +pdflatex +biber +pdflatex +pdflatex`

I will share a couple of screen captures to help you started.

[image: a]

[image: b]

If you run the MWE of the link you mention the full process will run by itself. (I am using MikTeX)

As output you should get

[image: z]

From [Follow-up to "How to call biber"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610940/follow-up-to-how-to-call-biber)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\listfiles % see the list of loaded file at the end of the log file

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-icomp,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
doi=true,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{kastenholz}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{sigfridsson}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Inspect your console output of TeXstudio (midway) (or the `.blg` file with a text editor). I used a file named `biberMWE.tex`.

```
Process started: biber.exe "biberMWE"

biber: security risk: running with elevated privileges
INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'biberMWE.blg'
INFO - Reading 'biberMWE.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'biblatex-examples.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'C:/Users/simon/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nyt' and locale 'de_DE'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE'
INFO - Writing 'biberMWE.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to biberMWE.bbl
Process exited normally
```

The last line is the more important. You should look for this nice ending every time you change you `.bib` database or add a cite in your document.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I couldn't get back earlier to you... Unfortunately, I get an error and thus it doesn't work yet (with the MWE from the accepted answer), could you please take a brief look at my edited question?

Comment: @Hermi I updated my MWE by adding `\listfiles `at the beginning.

Run it and you will get a list of all loaded files and their version in the `.log` file. Add this * File List * to your question. Maybe an update is needed. Did your system run the entire sequence of compliations by itself?

Comment: I looked into the log file, there are 617 lines in there. How exactly do you want me to add the file to my question? :) Also: I'm afraid I do not understand your last question: "Did your system run the entire sequence of compliations by itself?"

Comment: @Hermi  Check in  Configure Texstudio, (1) screen Commands (1a) PdfLatex > `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode   -shell-escape %.tex`  (1b) Biber > `biber.exe %`

(2) screen Build (2a) Default Bibliography  Tool > `txs:///biber`  (2b) Recomplile Bibliography > `txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile`

Comment: @Hermi  Log file should start similar to `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.8.20)`.  Then close to the end must find `biblatex.sty    2020/12/31 v3.16 programmable bibliographies `

Comment: Thanks. Concerning 1b) under "Biber", it had said "Unknown command", I changed this to `biber.exe %` as you suggested, but it threw an error that "biber.exe" could not be started. With `biber %` only, it throws the same error that the command "biber" cannot be started. Under 2a), it says for me "Biber", there is only a dropdown menu, so I cannot type what you wrote. Under 2b), I am not sure where to find "Recompile Bibliography"?

Comment: ad log file: Yes, the beginning starts with `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.4.20)` and near the end I have `biblatex.sty    2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)`. Can it be that my BibLaTeX is outdated?

Comment: @Hermi  Its looks that you do not have biber installed. Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154754#154754 and more important https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538791/how-to-get-the-biber-script-with-a-custom-texlive-installation

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the second link you posted, but when I try to install biber via `tlgmr install biber` from the terminal, I get the following message: `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /home/user/texmf
tlmgr: running in usermode, did you call 'tlmgr init-usertree'?`.

Comment: @Hermi I can not help there. I suggest you ask another question like how to install biber with Debian/TexLive 2019  and show your last output. Biber must appear in the dropdown menu of TeXstudio,

Comment: Dear Simon Dispa, thanks for your help. :) The following link solved my problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612137/how-to-install-biber-with-tex-live-2019-debian.

Comment: @Hermi Great! So you finally were able to compile my example and your also your own document?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (-;