# How to install Biber with TeX Live 2019/Debian

Tags: texlive, biber

In the accepted answer of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538791/how-to-get-the-biber-script-with-a-custom-texlive-installation), it says:

> With TeX live you can (and should) normally install Biber via
>
> `tlmgr install biber`

Now, when I try to it via the terminal, it tells me:

`(running on Debian, switching to user mode!) TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /home/user/texmf tlmgr: running in usermode, did you call 'tlmgr init-usertree'`

What I found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137428/tlmgr-cannot-setup-tlpdb) on a related, though not exactly the same problem, is to run `tlmgr init-usertree`, but then I get the message

```
Command 'tlgmr' not found, did you mean:

  command 'tlmgr' from deb texlive-base (2019.20200218-1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

When I type `sudo apt install tlgmr`, I get the error `sudo: tlgmr: command not found` Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: don't use tlmgr to install any of the texlive components if you are using the debian version install it via apt as you woudl other debian packages

Comment: your final error is simply because you have a typo `tlmgr` not `tlgmr`  but you have that installed already, install biber

Comment: https://command-not-found.com/biber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer is correct for a 'vanilla' TeX live installed from TUG.org ([How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)). If you installed your TeX live via your Linux distribution and its package manager (`apt`, `yum`, ...), `tlmgr` is usually not usable (or should not be used, if it is usable). Instead you need to install LaTeX packages and support programs like Biber via your package manager.

In case of Biber and Debian that would be

```
sudo apt install biber
```

---

Note that if you use the TeX live from your Linux distribution's package manager, you may well lag behind recent developments a bit (for many non-rolling-release distros the TeX live gets frozen at some point and is never updated, so Ubuntu LTS versions end up with a pretty outdated TeX live after a while). A majority of users will not have an issue with that. But if you happen to need cutting edge features, your best bet is to get a 'vanilla' TeX live instead: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864).