# How to change bytranslator field in bibliography which uses biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, compiling

I have a problem with biblatex not wanting to use Serbian language and compiling wrong.
[image: Bibliography with bytranslator]

```
%Compile with XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt,serbian]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR,]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[script=latin]{serbian}
\setotherlanguages{english,russian,greek}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,autolang=other,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\bibliography{ref}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{serbian}{
  bytranslator = {prev.}
}


\title{Dnevnik čitanja}
\author{Perović Nikola}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage

\section*{Voltaire (Volter)}
\subsection*{Kandid}

„Sve je neizbežno vezano jedno s drugim i najbolje udešeno.“\smartcite[str.13]{Vol02}

„Sve je u svetu najbolje što može biti.“\smartcite[str.14]{Vol02}

„I nesreće pojedinca čine opšte dobro; otuda, što je više pojedinih nesreća utoliko je sve bolje.“\smartcite{Vol02}

„Ako je sve najbolje što može biti onda nema pravog greha ni prave kazne.“\smartcite[str.13]{Vol02}


\newpage

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

ref.bib file

```
@BOOK{Vol02,
AUTHOR="Volter",
TITLE="Kandid",
TRANSLATOR="Milan Predić",
PUBLISHER="Alfa",
LOCATION="Beograd",
YEAR="2002",
HYPHENATION="serbian"
}
```

How can I change **bytranslator** to say prev. instead?

Comment: Not related to the issue, but if this document is to be compiled with XeLaTeX as the comment at the top says, you probably don't want to be loading `\usepackage[T1,LGR,]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}` (not sure about `\usepackage{textalpha}`).

Comment: Now this is curious, when I run your MWE I get Cyrillic Serbian and not Latin Serbian. What version of `biblatex` are you running?

Comment: I am using biber to compile bib files and its version is 2.14

Comment: OK, so that would be `biblatex` 3.14. In the recently released `biblatex` 3.15 the Serbian localisation was improved vastly (meaning, it was added in the first place, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/940). You may want to update.

Comment: I'm noticing a weird effect with `polyglossia` though: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/442

Comment: Do things work if you say `\DefineBibliographyStrings{serbianc}` instead of `\DefineBibliographyStrings{serbian}`? In that case this would just be the `polyglossia` issue.

Comment: It seems that the problem is still with biblatex because it won't use serbian. ! Package biblatex Error: Language 'serbianc' not found.

Comment: Yeah, like I said. `biblatex` 3.14 doesn't have a Serbian localisation. It was only added in `biblatex` 3.15. If you can't update or don't want to, you have to make do with defining everything manually.

Comment: Can you tell me how to manually update it? I've run pacman update but I doesn't seem like the update is live yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you are using `biblatex` v3.14. The Serbian localisation `serbian.lbx` and `serbianc.lbx` was only added in `biblatex` v3.15, which was released a few weeks ago. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/940. So you are essentially using a `biblatex` version with no Serbian support whatsoever.

The best solution would be to **update your TeX distribution so you get `biblatex` 3.15 (and Biber 2.15 etc.)**.

If you installed your TeX distribution via your Linux distribution's package manager, there may be no way to obtain an update to a recent TeX system.

In that case you have three options.

1. Install a current 'vanilla' TeX Live from TUG.org (see e.g. [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)). You'll have full control over that system and can update packages via `tlmgr` ([How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864)). But note that TeX Live is released in yearly versions. You'll have to update each year if you want to stay up-to-date.
2. Try to update only `biblatex` and Biber manually. There are some instructions (for older `biblatex`/Biber versions) at [How to upgrade 'biblatex' properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84624/35864). But this is usually absolutely not recommended: It can lead to version incompatibilities and manual installations of Biber are a major source of headache in the `biblatex` world.
3. Only get `serbian.lbx` from `biblatex` v3.15 and drop it into your document folder. You can download it from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/lbx/serbian.lbx. You may get a number of weird errors when you try to run your document with that `.lbx` files. If you are lucky, you can resolve them easily.  (If you get errors about an undefined string `<string>`, add `\NewBibliographyString{<string>}` to your preamble, e.g. `\NewBibliographyString{langserbian}`).

Only option 1 is one I would recommend. The other options are quite risky (option 2) or are bound to need manual intervention (option 3).

I think I managed to get option 3 working, but there might be some issues there that I don't see due to some interferences on my system.

---

Unrelated to your `biblatex` issues, `polyglossia` has a small inconsistency with regards to its `babelname` interface for Serbian, which currently confuses `biblatex` a bit: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/442.