# Bibliography section doesn't appear

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have a `trial.tex` file with the following content:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{trial_ref.bib}

\begin{document}

2 plus 2 equals 4.\parencite{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And then a `trial_ref.bib` file located at the same directory:

```
@article{test,
    author = {Pythagoras},
    title = {On the result of 2 + 2},
    journaltitle = {Ellinikos Mathematikos},
    year = {100 bC}
}
```

However I don't get a bibliography section at all.

Comment: Did you actually run `biber`? It does not happen automatically? You need to run something similar to `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`. With that your example works fine for me.

Comment: Did you compile your document with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...)? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains why that is necessary (the linked answer is for both BibTeX and Biber, but you need to run Biber). If you work from an editor and your editor runs LaTeX for you, you may have to configure it for Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If you did run Biber there should be a `.blg` file (a simple text file) that logs all warnings and errors.

Comment: Not related to the problem,  the best way to record BC/BCE dates is to use the `date` field, and use the `-0100` format. For more info see Section 2.3.8 of the Biblatex manual

Comment: Ok, so I ran it once with `pdfLaTeX`, then once with `Biber`, and then twice with `pdfLaTeX`. However it doesn't work. When I run it with `biber` I get the following error: `INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'trial.blg'
INFO - Reading 'trial.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.3, expected version 3.8.
This means that your biber (2.17) and biblatex (3.7) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1`. I'm using rhe TexWorks IDE.

Comment: Let me guess: are you on MikTeX? If so please update your MikTeX both in MikTeX user mode and in MikTeX admin mode. You seem to have differentiating versions of `biber` and `biblatex`, these need to match.

Comment: BTW: the editor (here TeXWorks) is irrelevant

Comment: No, I'm on TeXLive.

Comment: How did you install TeX live (if you installed via your OS's package manager like `apt`/`apt-get`, please mention your OS)? Did you install any packages manually? Do you maybe have several TeX live installations on your machine?

Comment: I installed it from here: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html. My OS is OpenSuse Leap 15.3.. I haven't installed any packages manually. How can I know if I have TeXLive installed more than once? I think I don't.

Comment: By the way after following these steps (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84656/120810) the error I get when I run it with `biber` is: `execve: Permission denied`.

Comment: Do **not** follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84656/35864, unless you know exactly what you are doing and why you are doing it. Manual Biber installations do not keep in synch with `biblatex` and are generally not necessary. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447539/35864. What do you get when you type `which -a tlmgr`, `which -a pdflatex`, `which -a biber` in the command line? What do you get if you type `kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty`?

Comment: ... The error message says you have Biber 2.17 (which is the current version), but `biblatex` is at version 3.7 (from December 2016)! It is pretty odd that the `biblatex` version is so old. It is possible that you don't have several TeX live installations, but a local outdated copy of `biblatex.sty` somewhere. In addition to the output of the queries from my comment above, can you upload the `.log` file of the LaTeX run on the example document to a text-sharing site such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/, please?

Comment: This is the content of `trial.log`: https://pastebin.com/xtZmNmLH

Comment: `~> which -a tlmgr` outputs `which: no tlmgr in (/home/bscuser/.local/bin:/home/bscuser/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin)`; `~> which -a pdflatex` outputs `/usr/bin/pdflatex`;  `~> which -a biber` outputs `which: no biber in (/home/bscuser/.local/bin:/home/bscuser/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin)`; `~> kpsewhich -all biblatex.sty` outputs `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`.

Comment: Do you remember the location of the TeX system you installed from https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html. From what I can see, the TeX system that is in the PATH is very outdated and does not come with `tlmgr` indicating it is from your OS package manager. Can you show us a screenshot of your TeXmaker "Commands" settings where you configure all the programs?

Comment: I'm not using Texmaker but TeXworks (as far as I understand both are editors). Anyway, under "Configuration and Resources" there's: "Configuration": `/home/bscuser/.config/TUG/TeXworks.conf` and "Resources": `/home/bscuser/.TeXworks/`. (https://imgur.com/8aGH2TK). The location of the file I installed from that page is `/home/bscuser/Downloads/`.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, I got confused with some other post about the editor. Can you show a screenshot of the Texworks preferences, specifically the *path* information at the top of the "typesetting" tab, please? Did you really install your TeX system into `/home/bscuser/Downloads/`? Normally, when you install from TUG.org, you get an install script that guides you through the installation and lets you select a installation directory? Did you actually run the script you downloaded? What directory did you tell it to install into?

Comment: Screenshot (https://imgur.com/6QbEFtA, "Typesetting", first dropdown: "Path to TeX and related programs", second dropdown: "Typesetting tools"). There is no guide here, and the `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` is indeed in `/home/bscuser/Downloads/`. What I did was unpack that directory and follow the instructions under "Running the installer"(https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). `cd /your/unpacked/directory
perl install-tl
[... messages omitted ...]
Enter command: i`

Comment: In the "Typesetting" window use the arrows to move up the currently last path `/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux` to the top. Delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and compile again. Hopefully that already works. You definitely have two TeX systems. One is probably system installed, but does not include all of TeX Live. You also have the vanilla TeX live from TUG. If you change the PATH settings to prefer the TUG TeX Live we'll hopefully no longer have version mismatches.