# Remove the comma between family name and given name

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with `biber` in the `numeric-comp` style.
I'm calling `biblatex` as follows:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,giveninits=true,terseinits=true]{biblatex‌​}
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
```

With this I get almost what I want. But I would like to remove the comma between the family name and the initials. Can you help me with that?

Edit: I know how this works with the old version "last-first" and I would like to do the same with the newer "family-given".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you actually tried if `\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}` as suggested in [biblatex: remove commas between last and first names in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17583/35864) works for you? It certainly works for me. So if you have troubles getting it to do what you want, please also provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows how it didn't work for you. Otherwise I believe your question *is* a duplicate, since `\revsdnamepunct` works for `family-given` as well as it does for `last-first`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your suggestion works fine. I overlooked this possibility in the other thread because there was also a more complicated method suggested. And sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: OK, I have closed your question as a duplicate after all.