# Removing comma from journal title in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I don't know why but journal title field incorrectly displays comma. It looks like `“Journal title,”`, but should be `“Journal title”,`. I have tried like 5 multiple fixes found online, nothing helps.

Alternatively I could accept reformating, but I don't know how to do it. I mean make journal title display like book title (for example `Journal title` without quotation marks in cursive), and make journal name field display with plain text without cursive.

It's out of the scope of the question but I also can't figure out how to remove comma between author name and surname. It displays `Doe, J.` but should be `Doe J.`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[
bibstyle=ieee,
citestyle=numeric,
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits=true]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\title{Example}
\author{Overleaf}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
Cite. 
\cite{author00} \cite{author01} \cite{author02}

\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography file:

```
@book{author00,
    title = {Book Title},
    author = {John Doe and Adam Smith and Peter Parker and John Edwards and George R. Martin},
    year = {2023},
    publisher = {Publisher}
}

@book{author01,
    title = {Book Title Part 2},
    author = {John Goldberg and Adam Peterson and Peter Parker and John Edwards and George R. Martin},
    year = {2023},
    publisher = {Publisher}
}

@article{author02,
    title = {Journal Title},
    author = {John Doe},
    year = {2020},
    journal = {Journal Name},
    volume = {11},
    number = {6}
}
```

Comment: For the question about the comma between family and given name see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17583/35864.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comma placement is typical for American English: Following punctuation is moved inside quotation marks even if it does not "logically" belong there. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#American_style.

This behaviour is usually only enabled for `biblatex`'s American localisation and not the generic `english`, but `biblatex-ieee` requests it explicitly with `\uspunctuation` (see [l. 34 in `ieee.bbx`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/blob/7f67eea42f55ee0c27c8358dd7cd64bf47ad4a4c/ieee.bbx#L34).) You can counter that with a simple `\stdpunctuation`.

Usually `\uspunctuation` and `\stdpunctuation` should be used inside `\DefineBibliographyExtras`, but since `biblatex-ieee` uses it outside, we will counter it outside as well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
  bibstyle=ieee,
  citestyle=numeric,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\stdpunctuation
%\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\stdpunctuation}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author00,
    title = {Book Title},
    author = {John Doe and Adam Smith and Peter Parker and John Edwards and George R. Martin},
    year = {2023},
    publisher = {Publisher}
}
@book{author01,
    title = {Book Title Part 2},
    author = {John Goldberg and Adam Peterson and Peter Parker and John Edwards and George R. Martin},
    year = {2023},
    publisher = {Publisher}
}
@article{author02,
    title = {Journal Title},
    author = {John Doe},
    year = {2020},
    journal = {Journal Name},
    volume = {11},
    number = {6}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}
Cite. 
\cite{author00,author01,author02}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: Doe, J., “Journal title”, Journal Name, vol. 11, no. 6, 2020.]