# Biblatex citation formating -- author name formatting

Tags: biblatex

I got the rest of the citation in the format I want, but I having trouble adjusting the format of the author names.

### Example:

```tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

% Document margins
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% citation formatting start
% hyperlinks and citation coloring
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp, 
    sorting=none, 
    backend=biber,
    giveninits=true, 
    minbibnames=3, maxbibnames=3,
    citestyle=numeric,
    parentracker=true
]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
     \printfield{labelnumber}%
     \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
       {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
       {}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printnames[family-given]{author}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{journaltitle}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \iffieldundef{number}{}{%
    \printtext{(}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \printtext{)}%
  }%
  \setunit{\addcolon}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% TODO: fix author naming
% Should look like "<family_name> <given_first_initial><given_second_initial>"

% remove parenthesis around title
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

% Adjust label format
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.\hfill}

% remove pp. identifier
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% remove space between volume(number)
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \iffieldundef{number}{}{%
    \printtext{\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{number}}%
  }%
}

%% end citation formatting %%

% read bibliography
\begin{filecontents*}{my_bib.bib}
@article{money_in_the_banana_stand,
  title = {{Blueing yourself: The Most Efficient Method for Nevernudes}},
  author = {Fünke, Tobias and Bluth, George Michael and Bluth, Buster and Fünke, Maeby},
  date = {2200-01-04},
  journaltitle = {Ladies of Lit},
  volume = {420},
  number = {69},
  pages = {303--404},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{my_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

And that is why you should always abide by Bob Loblaw's Law Blog \cite*{money_in_the_banana_stand}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### The *current* resulting document:

[image: latex_rendered]

### What I want:

> not-tex, LM Roman 12

[image: non tex]

Please notice the author naming covention that I want my citations to follow. `"<family-name> <given-initials>"`

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17583/35864. You probably want the `terseinits=true,` option and `\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}`.

Comment: Any news here? As far as I can tell https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17583/35864 is exactly what you want.